# Populate Menu From Category links - for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to find what's wrong with my loop. I keep receiving this TypeError and I'm tried moving things around but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I am trying to populate a list by adding an event listener on click to my category headings. When I click, a 4 picture grid should show up with all items of the category listed. However, I receive this error:

main.js:98 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.populateItems (main.js:98)

```js
var cart = [];

var dairyItems = [{
        img: 'images\Dairy\butter.png',
        name: 'Butter'
    },

    {
        img: 'images\Dairy\milk.png',
        name: 'Milk'
    },

    {
        img: 'images\Dairy\sour cream.png',
        name: 'Sour Cream'
    },

    {
        img: 'images\Dairy\yogurt.png',
        name: 'Yogurt'
    }
];

var meatItems = [{
        img: 'images\Meat\chicken-breast.png',
        name: 'Chicken Breasts'
    },

    {
        img: 'images\Meat\ground-beef.png',
        name: 'Ground Beef'
    },

    {
        img: 'images\Meat\pork-chops.png',
        name: 'Pork Chops'
    },

    {
        img: 'images\Meat\t-bone.png',
        name: 'T-Bone Steak'
    }
];

var produceItems = [{
        img: '\images\Produce\avocado.png',
        name: 'Avocados'
    },

    {
        img: '\images\Produce\broccoli.png',
        name: 'Broccoli'
    },

    {
        img: '\images\Produce\cauliflower.png',
        name: 'Cauliflower'
    },

    {
        img: 'images\Produce\lettuce.png',
        name: 'Lettuce'
    }
];

var dairy = document.getElementById('dairy').addEventListener('click', populateItems);

var meat = document.getElementById('meat').addEventListener('click', populateItems);

var produce = document.getElementById('produce').addEventListener('click', populateItems);

//-----------------ADD TO CART--------------//


//----------------ADD TO SCREEN-------------//


function populateItems(category) {
    
    clearpopulateItems();

    var myItems;
    switch(category) {
        case 'dairy':
            myItems = dairyItems;
            break;
        case 'meat':
            myItems = meatItems;
            break;
        case 'produce':
            myItems = produceItems;
            break;
        default:
    }


    var categoryList = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
    for(var i = 0; i < myItems.length; i++) {
        myItems[i].addEventListener('click', addCat);
        function addCat() {categoryList.append(
            `<li class='items'>
                <img src='${currentItem.img}'>
                <p>${currentItem.name}</p>
            </li>`);
        }
    }


    document.getElementById('items').append(categoryList);
 

function clearpopulateItems() {
    var items = document.getElementById('items')
    while(items.firstChild) items.removeChild(items.firstChild);
}

function addToCart(item) {
    document.querySelectorAll('ul').append(`
    <li>
            ${item}
    </li>`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDITED

[image]

I'm not going to copy the code. You have to fix it.

- In your last code you are setting `dairyItems` twice.
- When you add the eventListener, `populateItems` needs an argument.
- Yo cannot do this `myItems[i].addEventListener` because it's not an HTML element. It's an array of Objects
- You haven't declared `currentItem`.
- Etc.

Comment: Thank you. I think I see what you mean, is it the order of my code that's out of whack? Or am I missing creating an element?

Comment: You have several errors, e.g. in the `switch case`, `myItems`  will be an array of objects and you cannot add EventListeners to them `myItems[i].addEventListener()`;

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code to this snippet. There is error, because you call code on DOM elements which are not created. First of all DOM needs to be loaded, then you can use DOM API.

```js
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 // your whole code 
});
```

...or you can add your code to the end of HTML, then JS code will be loaded after DOM is rendered.

Comment: OK I did, for some reason it still gives me the same error. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have an element with the id `dairy`. That's why its null. Confirm that you have created the element first then try again.

Comment: Ah yes, that was a typo that I have corrected, still gives me the same error regarding .length however.